# Camera in Blender 2.8 only rendering the background

Tags: rendering, camera

I am currently modelling a kitchen bench and sink, and I went to make a test render, but it just showed up as the background color. no matter how I aligned the camera the render stayed the same.
[image]

I am currently in rendered view.

Any help would be appriciated, and if you need me to clarify anything I would be glad to.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up/67501#67501

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your collection is disabled for render:

[image]

Hit this camera icon to enable it:

[image]

Also check render state for individual objects

Comment: Thanks... I feel quite dumb now, I remembered to check that for all items but not the collection...